# Is there a way to use get_F00_display in parallel with values() in Django views.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

**What I want to do :**

Display the human readable value of a charfield with choices via get_F00_display or other in views.py and then in template.

models.py

```
class Leave(CommonFields):

LEAVES_TYPES = [
        ('10', _('Type 1')),
        ('20', _('Type 2')),
        ('30', _('Type 3')),
        ]


owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LEAVES_TYPES, null=True, default="10")


def __str__(self):
    return self.owner.first_name + " " + self.owner.last_name + " : du " + self.begin_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + " au " + self.end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Leave.objects.filter(is_active=True).values('type', 'begin_date','end_date','range','comment','status')
```

leave_list.html

```
<td>{{leave.type}}</td>
```

BUT :
I want to return `{{leave.get_type_display}}` and at the same time `Leave.objects.filter(is_active=True).**values**(...)`
How to ? Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Please *don't* use `.values`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please *don't* use values. The main reason not to do this, is exactly the one you describe in the question: [*primitive obsession* <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). If you want to limit the number of columns that you aim to fetch, you can use [**`.only(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#only) or [**`.defer(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#defer) to specify what columns *not* to fetch:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Leave.objects.filter(is_active=True).only(
        'type', 'begin_date', 'end_date', 'range', 'comment', 'status'
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).